# Ternary operator difficult to read

Tags: c#, conditional-operator

Any suggestion how to make the below query more "readable"?

```
var result = result
                .OrderBy(a =>
                    (conditionA) ?
                    valueA :
                    (conditionB ? valueB :
                    (conditionC ?
                    (conditionD ?
                    valueC : valueD) :
                    valueE)));
```

Its difficult to read with the long code of condition and value.

Comment: Add proper indentation and align colons `:` with their corresponding questino marks `?`

Comment: [tag:ternary-operator]: "A ternary operator is **any** operator that takes three arguments. For the ternary conditional operator `?`...`:`, use `[tag:conditional-operator]`." (My *emphasis*)

Comment: Better yet *remove all the conditions*. You add `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` statements in code, they are just functions. If you want to specify the ordering field dynamically, you can do so easily in LINQ

Comment: depends on the condition. For simple conditions I'd just re-align the code. For complex conditions I'd consider extracting a delegate

Comment: Actually, @PanagiotisKanavos, this effect cannot be implemented using a `OrderBy` / `ThenBy` chain, because depending on the conditions, comparisons might end up comparing `left.valueA` to `right.valueC` or any other combination.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways of improving the readability of your code.

**Indentation**

One way is to indent the code in a slightly different way, but this only helps readability a little:

```
var result = result.OrderBy(a =>
    conditionA ? valueA :
    conditionB ? valueB :
    conditionC ? conditionD ? valueC :
                              valueD :
                valueE);
```

**if, else**

You could also turn those ternary operators into a more readable chain of `if`, `else`.

```
var result = Result.OrderBy(a => {
    if (conditionA)
    {
        return valueA;
    }
    else if (conditionB)
    {
        return valueB;
    }
    else if (conditionC)
    {
        if (conditionD)
        {
            return valueC;
        }
        else
        {
            return valueD;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return valueE;
    }
});
```

**IComparer<>**

One option would be to write your own implementation of `IComparer<>` and pass it to the `OrderBy` method. I don't know what type your object is or what type the keys are in your code, so I'm going to assume `string` keys.

```
public class MyClassComparer : IComparer<MyClass>
{
    public int Compare(MyClass x, MyClass y)
    {
        string xKey = getKey(x);
        string yKey = getKey(y);
        return string.Compare(xKey, yKey);
    }

    private string getKey(MyClass item)
    {
        if (item.conditionA)
        {
            return item.valueA;
        }
        else if (item.conditionB)
        {
            return item.valueB;
        }
        else if (item.conditionC)
        {
            if (item.conditionD)
            {
                return item.valueC;
            } 
            else
            {
                return item.valueD;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return item.valueE;
        }
    }
}
```

**Extension method**

A final option would be to move your code to an extension method:

```
public static class MyClassExtensions
{
    public static string GetSortingKey(this MyClass item)
    {
        if (item.conditionA)
        {
            return item.valueA;
        }
        else if (item.conditionB)
        {
            return item.valueB;
        }
        else if (item.conditionC)
        {
            if (item.conditionD)
            {
                return item.valueC;
            } 
            else
            {
                return item.valueD;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return item.valueE;
        }
    }
}
```

Using the last option, your call to `OrderBy` is simply:

```
result.OrderBy(a => a.GetSortingKey())
```

Comment: That's what I would do too. Multiple ternary operators are just too hard to understand even when you know all of the parsing rules.